# apply pagination dynamically to jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid, pagination

I need to apply pagination to jqgrid dynamiacally for json data in my jsp page(that is client-side)

```
$(window).resize( function(){
//I need pagination code here
}
```

Comment: I personally would not like to work with the grid having page size as 13 or 23. If you use `height: "auto"` and some reasonable `rowNum` like 10 or 20 you will have good results. Isn't so? You can allow the user to change the page size additionally with respect of `rowList` option.

Comment: @Oleg the thing is that if I am using a normal monitor there is no need of pagination, but when the same grid is shown in a bigger monitor the row height is increasing based on the screen height, as I had set the grid height same as that of the screen height.If the screen resolution (height) increases the number of data shown inside the grid should increase to fit the grid height with default row height